# Netbeans IDE not issuing warnings about methods called in constructors

Tags: java, netbeans

Netbeans IDE is good at spotting code that could give you trouble. Why is a warning not issued for

```
public class Base
{
    Base(...)
    {
        ...;
    }

    public void foo()
    {
        ...;
    }
}

public class Child extends Base
{
    Child(...)
    {
        super(...);
        foo();
    }
}
```

given that I'm calling the base class function foo() in the child constructor? Of course that's perfectly legitimate as the base object is constructed by the point foo() is called, but a foo() is implicitly a virtual method so really I would expect a warning *unless foo() is marked final*.

I think that the IDE should issue a warning if you call any base class function from a child class constructor that is not marked as final.

Comment: You mean `foo()` is abstract ? `abstract void foo();` ?

Comment: No not at all. It has implementation. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Consider to file an issue, if you think it's a bug: https://netbeans.org/community/issues.html

Comment: I'm so new to Java, I would like to get my facts straight first.

Comment: Does it show a warning if you mark your method `foo` `public` or `protected`?

Comment: foo is public; I've amended the question text.

Comment: It might be somewhat in bad style, but it is completely legitimate Java code.

Comment: @pfyod - I agree it is legitimate and bad code but my (humblish) opinion is that you should get a warning.

Comment: @Bathsheba This is debatable. On the other hand, if `Base` had a call to overridable `foo()` in it's constructor, then it would be most definitely bad code:  `Base` constructor runs before `Child`, and thus bugs are possible (`Child`'s `foo` referencing some field of `Child`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does.
When you open the file in NetBeans, you should see a yellow lightbulb (hint indicator) next to the call to `foo`. It's a suggestion that you either:

- Make Child final
- Make foo final, private, or static

If you want it to be more obvious, go to `Tools > Options`, or `Edit > Preferences`, or `Netbeans > Preferences` (depends on your OS).
Choose `Editor`
Choose `Hints`
Set `Language` to `Java`
Expand `Initialization`
Select `Problematic call in the constructor`
Change `Show as` to `Error`
Click `OK`

Now the line as well as your file will get a red error badge.

Note, none of this will *prevent* you from ignoring the indicator. The code is still legal Java, so NB will not prevent you from compiling.